# My Select Statement won't give me column from Table

Tags: sql-server-2012

what is wrong with this query? I do have column called percet with tinyint.
please help

SELECT  LC.ID , LC.DESCRIPTION , LC.CHANGEDBYID , LP.PERCENT ,  LP.ADDEDBYID , LP.DATEADDED FROM LIKELIHOODTYPECODE LC  JOIN LIKELIHOODPERCENT LP ON LC.ID = LP.ID;

If I do Select * from likelihoodpercent then it will show all my column with percent, but when I do select percent from likelihoodpercent then it give me error.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error it is giving you?

Comment: Incorrect syntax. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PERCENT` is a SQL Server keyword. To use it in a query, put square brackets around it:

```
SELECT LC.ID , LC.DESCRIPTION , LC.CHANGEDBYID , LP.[PERCENT] , LP.ADDEDBYID , LP.DATEADDED FROM LIKELIHOODTYPECODE LC JOIN LIKELIHOODPERCENT LP ON LC.ID = LP.ID;
```